# Google Guice binding not working with Integer and Long

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Error when using Google Guice.

Could not find a suitable constructor in java.lang.Long. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
  at java.lang.Long.class

```
class DIModule extends AbstractModule {
   protected void configure(){
      bind(Long.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("seconds")).toInstance(1574965800000L);
   }
}
```

Using lombok for Constructor

```
@AllArgsConstructor (onConstructor_ = { @Inject })
class Cat{
   @Named("seconds")
   private Long time;
}
```

But below one works without error.

```
class Cat{
  private Long time;
  @Inject
  public Cat(@Named("seconds") Long time){
     this.time = time;
  }
}
```

can someone explain me how to make it work with Lombok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to have all instances of the `@Named` annotations on fields copied to the corresponding constructor parameter by adding [`lombok.copyableAnnotations`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/ConfigurationKeys.html#COPYABLE_ANNOTATIONS) to your [lombok.config](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration) file, like this:

```
lombok.copyableAnnotations += com.google.inject.name.Named
```